# Use Require in both VirtualHost and .htaccess

Tags: apache, config

I want to have GeoIP checking in `VirtualHost` and on success to have the `.htaccess` file of the webpage to be processed, which also has some `Require` directives set (for its files).

I use macros and environment vars for dynamic configs, so currently my vhost config looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost ${myIP4}:443>
...
<Directory "/srv/www/$domain/htdocs">
    MaxMindDBEnable On
    MaxMindDBFile COUNTRY_DB /var/lib/GeoIP/GeoLite2-Country.mmdb
    MaxMindDBEnv MM_COUNTRY_CODE COUNTRY_DB/country/iso_code
    SetEnvIf MM_COUNTRY_CODE "^$countries" PassCountry

    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
    Require env PassCountry
</Directory>
```

This works fine when access for `$countries` should be revoked, as the `Require all denied` wins.
But when it's a valid country code, the .htaccess file should get executed, for which I would need an `AllowOverride All` here.

I tried several ways like

```
<If "reqenv('PassCountry') == 1">
    AllowOverride All
</If>
```

but the if clause seems not to be evaluated correctly.

But that's not the only problem. Also when adding same in the else tree (for testing purposes)

```
<Else>
    AllowOverride All
</Else>
```

it is not recognized although it says that it can be used within if clauses.

*Only directives that support the directory context can be used within this configuration section.*

see https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/core.html#if

So how could I solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it now by using `mod_rewrite` like that:

```
MaxMindDBEnable On
MaxMindDBFile COUNTRY_DB /var/lib/GeoIP/GeoLite2-Country.mmdb
MaxMindDBEnv MM_COUNTRY_CODE COUNTRY_DB/country/iso_code
SetEnvIf MM_COUNTRY_CODE "^$countries" PassCountry=1

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{ENV:PassCountry} !1
# allow showing error documents (maybe required to be adopted when not using defaults)
RewriteRule !(^/error/) "-" [F]
```

But this does not work inside the `<Directory>` directive, so move it out from there.